# Issues when deleting data in database

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm using sqlite database, I'm displaying data in tableview, when I delete row in tableview that data should also delete in my db table. I write query for deleting but it not deleting in my sqlitedb table.

Here is my code

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{

    if (btnCliked==NO)
    {

        [videoTitleArrya removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [videoImagesLinksDataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"videoTitleArrya%@",videoTitleArrya);
        NSLog(@"videoImagesLinksDataArray%@",videoImagesLinksDataArray);
        NSUInteger temp=[[videoTitleArrya objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue];
        [self deleteDataBaseRow:temp];

      }


    [tableView reloadData];
}
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
{

}
}

 -(void)deleteDataBaseRow:(NSUInteger)RowNumber

   {
       if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &DB)==SQLITE_OK)
      {
    NSLog(@"dataBaseOpen");
    NSString *Query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE  FROM mytablename where 
     id ='%@'",RowNumber];

    const char * deletequery = [Query UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(DB, deletequery, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {

     NSLog(@"deletedSuccessfully");

    }
  sqlite3_close(DB);

}}
```

Comment: Show the table definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code i would like to take care of some points and if all other things are proper it will remove records from database.

Look at this line:

```
NSString *Query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE  FROM mytablename where 
 id ='%@'",RowNumber];
```

Here you use `%@` operator for `int` variable `RowNumber`. Replace above line with this

```
NSString *strRowNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",RowNumber];
NSString *Query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM mytablename where id ='%@'",strRowNumber];
```

Second thing to observe is below line:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(DB, deletequery, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
{
   NSLog(@"deletedSuccessfully");    
}
```

Here you have print `NSLog` for `!= SSQLITE_OK`. So above logic shows that you print successful message when there is error while removing row from table.  It is a  contradiction, and if you done any stuff in above condition than it will not take effect because your comparison is wrong.

Replace above condition with below:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
   if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
      sqlite3_reset(statement);
   }
   else {
      const char *error = sqlite3_errmsg(database);
      strError = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:error];
      NSLog(@"Error : %@",strError);
   }
} else {
   NSLog(@"Error while deleting record");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

deleting from a view will delete from the original table only if your view is not a complex view.

say for example, if the view is actually a join, they can only be used for querying. delete update etc wont work